# How do you use a Facebook user object to get your own user object?

Tags: c#, facebook

I am doing a little work with Facebook Connect and wondering how on Stack Overflow for example, you are able to login using another login provider such as Facebook or Yahoo, and for the site to be able to pick up your user details as you registered them on Stack Overflow?  As far as I am aware, you could have registered using a different email address and your first name and last name are not unique identifiers, so how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would most likely add a new column on to your user table such as facebook_uid. Then, if a user has an existing account, you would get them to sign in to that first, before connecting to facebook, you can then store their facebook_uid against your existing user_id. Then if the user turns up and is already signed in to facebook, you can sign them into your website as well. If the user doesn't have an existing account on your site, you would simply create one (possibly filling it with the users name from facebook)

If you wanted to allow multiple methods of sign in, you could potentially have another table that holds a mapping between a provider (facebook,twitter,google etc) and the associated id for that account back to your user table.

The basics are, when they sign in with a 3rd party login system, you either map it to a current account on your site, or you create new account on your site if one does not already exist, and you map the account to it. You would obviously need to make this clear to your users, or have some way to merge accounts in case they aren't already signed in when they use a 3rd party. You could also potentially ask for email access from facebook and try and map that to an existing account, before creating a new one

Thanks

Comment: How would you get them to sign in to their existing account before connecting to Facebook?

Comment: You'd ask them, that's down to you. You either only let them connect if they have an existing account or you create an account on your site the first time they connect

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your use case. For example, I use the e-mail address as a unique identifier. When you log in with Facebook, my portal also asks your e-mail address from Facebook. Then, it searches a user object with a matching e-mail address from the database.

There are more than one ways of doing this:

- Only allow login via Facebook. Then you can definitely identify all of your users via their e-mail address.
- Allow logging in via Facebook and a username/password too, but require your users to use the same e-mail address in both places.
- Allow logging in via Facebook and a username/password too, and allow your users to use different e-mail addresses for each. This is the most complicated option. Most sites solve this by requiring the user to 'pair' their Facebook account with their site account. This means that first time it is set up, users need to log in to the site, and while they're logged in to the site, they can log in to Facebook. Then your site stores their Facebook identity (no e-mail required in this case, just store the user id in a field). After this, the users can login via Facebook only, and you can pair their Facebook user id with the corresponding user object in your own database.

If you have any questions, just write them in the comments. :)

Comment: So when a user registers on your site, you have a field 'Facebook Email Address'? That sounds like a good idea, though how many users actually fill it in when registering?

Comment: Nope, I have a single e-mail field.

Comment: What if they register with a different email address to their Facebook email address?

Comment: @user517406 - That's why I said it all depends on your use case. I changed my answer to give you some more detail. :)

Comment: Thanks...I have taken bits from your suggestion and the other poster's suggestion, but I have decided to go with the Facebook ID as a unique identifier and so chose his answer as the accepted answer.  But I also voted up your answer as you also gave some useful advice.